# sending mail inserts a random space at the 995th character in the "to:" email list

Tags: php, string, email, character, line-breaks

Im using php's mail() function to send an e-mail to multiple receivers.

If i enter as the first parameter of the "mail" function something like "example1@example.com,example2@example.com,example3@example.com,example4@example.com,example5@example.com,example6@example.com........" a string of more than 1000 characters, when I receive the e-mail I see a " "(an empty space) being inserted at about the 995th character and whatever e-mail was at that position is broken.

I read that this is because the mail server doesn't accept very long lines of string so you should insert a "\n" at every 70 or so characters.
Therefore, I tried using wordwrap($emailList) that should insert line-breaks.

Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem and I'm running out of ideas right now.

Comment: If you stock all your emails in a variable, and pass the variable to php email() function ?

Comment: try `\r\n` instead of just `\n`. and put the line break after every email, it's neater that way anyway.

Comment: still doesn't work even with \r\n ...

Comment: the only solution until now that I have found is to split the e-mails in groups of 10 e-mails each and send the mail for each group one after another

Comment: I found the solution... check my response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve this problem like this:
I have the to list in a $strTo variable which contains the emails like this "email1, email2, email3, email4, "... with each email separated by ", " .

Before doing the mail() function I did this:

```
if($strTo != ""){
    $strTo = wordwrap($strTo,900,"\r\n ");
    $strTo .= "\r\n";
}
```

Which means I put carriage return, new line and a white space at every 900 characters(without breaking any words) and finally, at the end of the string I inserta carriage return and line feed.

Answer (score 1):

wordwrap did not work for me. I guess it depends upon whether your mail server honor it or not. Also in my case the fold was occurring every 998th character.
I was able to solve using multiple 'To:' fields in message header. e.g.

```
header = <<EOF
From: xyz@xyz.com
To: abc1@abc.com, abc2@abc.com, abc3@abc.com, ...abc100@abc.com
CC: prq1@prq.com
Subject: 'my subject'
EOF
```

constructed multiple arrays of 20 each using array.each_slice(20). Then formed the header such that

```
header = <<EOF
From: xyz@xyz.com
To: abc1@abc.com, abc2@abc.com, abc3@abc.com, ...abc20@abc.com
To: abc21@abc.com, abc22@abc.com, abc23@abc.com, ...abc30@abc.com
To: abc31@abc.com, abc32@abc.com, abc33@abc.com, ...abc40@abc.com
CC: prq1@prq.com
Subject: 'my subject'
EOF
```

my mail server honored it.